# Automatically write to another sheet where

Tags: arrays, excel-formula, excel-2013

I'm currently using this template to log employee holiday requests 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/templates/employee-absence-schedule-TC103987167.aspx

I have added array formulas to give the specific number of days each month that an employee has had a Holiday / Unpaid leave / Sick / Late etc 
eg

```
=SUM(LEN(B5:AF5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B5:AF5,"H","")))/LEN("H")
```

and combined these totals to get a year overview but I still have to look through the sheets to get a full list of days they have requested and copy out the data.

Is there a formula I can put in so I can make a sheet for each employee that when H appears On sheet January B8-AF8 write sheet month name and the corresponding day and date in row 4.

I'm trying to achieve something like this as an automatic function?

I'm currently unable to post images but if you need me to elaborate please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want 1 sheet per employee?  As far as I know there isn't a way of adding sheets automatically without using some code (VBA or otherwise).  If you had the sheets already created then I'm sure that we could come up with a formula.

Anyway, here is some VBA code you can try out...It creates a new workbook to summarize the data in.  There isn't any error checking and it assumes that you're running it from the template that you provided.  Just add a button that calls `EmployeeSummary` and it should work.

```
Type DayOffType
    Month As String
    DayOfWeek As String
    Date As String
    Type As String
End Type

Type EmployeeType
    Name As String
    DaysOff() As DayOffType
    NumberOfDaysOff As Long
End Type

Private EmployeeData() As EmployeeType
Private EmployeeCount As Long

Sub EmployeeSummary()
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Call ReadSchedule(ThisWorkbook)
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    Call WriteSummary(wb, "H")
End Sub

Sub ReadSchedule(Book As Excel.Workbook)
Dim tbl As Excel.Range
Dim TableName As String
Dim sMonth As String, sDay As String
Dim iMonth As Integer, iDate As Integer
Dim iEmployee As Long, iRow As Long, iCol As Long

    For iMonth = 1 To 12
        sMonth = MonthName(iMonth)
        With Book.Worksheets(sMonth)
            TableName = "tbl" & sMonth
            Set tbl = .ListObjects(TableName).Range
            For iRow = 2 To tbl.Rows.Count - 1
                iEmployee = GetEmployee(tbl.Cells(iRow, 1))
                For iCol = 2 To tbl.Columns.Count - 1
                    If tbl.Cells(iRow, iCol) <> vbNullString Then
                        AddDayOff iEmployee, sMonth, tbl, iRow, iCol
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End With
    Next
End Sub

Private Function GetEmployee(Name As String)
Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To EmployeeCount - 1
        If EmployeeData(i).Name = Name Then Exit For
    Next
    If i >= EmployeeCount Then
        ReDim Preserve EmployeeData(EmployeeCount)
        EmployeeData(EmployeeCount).Name = Name
        EmployeeCount = EmployeeCount + 1
    End If
    GetEmployee = i
End Function

Private Sub AddDayOff(Employee As Long, Month As String, Table As Range, Row As Long, Col As Long)
    With EmployeeData(Employee)
        ReDim Preserve .DaysOff(.NumberOfDaysOff)
        With .DaysOff(.NumberOfDaysOff)
            .Date = Table.Cells(1, Col)
            .DayOfWeek = Table.Cells(0, Col)
            .Month = Month
            .Type = Table.Cells(Row, Col)
        End With
        .NumberOfDaysOff = .NumberOfDaysOff + 1
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub WriteSummary(Book As Excel.Workbook, Optional AbsenceType As String = "H")
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim cell As Excel.Range
Dim i As Long, d As Long
    Set ws = Book.Worksheets(1)
    For i = 0 To EmployeeCount - 1
        With ws
            .Name = EmployeeData(i).Name
            .Range("A1") = EmployeeData(i).Name
            Set cell = .Range("A2")
            For d = 0 To EmployeeData(i).NumberOfDaysOff - 1
                If EmployeeData(i).DaysOff(d).Type = AbsenceType Then
                    cell = EmployeeData(i).DaysOff(d).Month
                    cell.Offset(0, 1) = EmployeeData(i).DaysOff(d).DayOfWeek
                    cell.Offset(0, 2) = EmployeeData(i).DaysOff(d).Date
                    Set cell = cell.Offset(1, 0)
                End If
            Next
        End With
        Set ws = Book.Worksheets.Add(after:=Book.Worksheets(Book.Worksheets.Count))
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```